# How to store an array in heap?

Tags: arrays, c, string, memory, heap-memory

I'm a C beginner and I'm learning "heap" currently. One thing confuse me is can we store an array in heap? If we can, how? 
Say for example:

```
int main(void) {
  char sentence[] = "Please move me to heap.";// I want to store this sentence in heap
  printf("%s\n", sentence);
}
```

Can somebody clarify this point to me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look up malloc() and calloc()

Comment: How can you "learn heap" and not have heard of `malloc`? What sort of "learning" are you doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at [this C tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c-tutorial.html) and then have a look at `malloc`.

There is an example use of `malloc` [here](http://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-the-functions-malloc-and-free). If you are learning, it is better to read a slightly longer tutorial than for us to give you the answer in code as the former will better your understanding.